# UILabel text color is light

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uilabel

In UIView i have added a label , who's text color is white but when I changes the Alpha of the UIView to 0.25 the color of UILabel lighten If I change Alpha back to 1.0 the UILabel text color result is what I expect.

I have no clue how to change setup.
Screenshot is included.

Also the Alpha is same for the Toolbar and the result is same , icon image of button is also light.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal behaviour because if you change alpha of the parent view it will be propagated to the child views. You can maybe change not the parent view alpha but use `colorWithAlphaComponent` for this view background color.

e.g.

```
yourParentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy